# Commutative diagramm (tikzcd) in margin

Tags: margins, marginpar, tikz-cd

The following example gives me an error

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper,
            inner=10mm,
            outer=60mm,
            top=20mm,
            bottom=25mm,
            marginparsep=10mm,
            marginparwidth=40mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

foo
\marginpar{
\begin{tikzcd}
    E 
        \arrow[bend right=50]{rr}[,label=below:\scriptsize $g\circ f$]{}
        \arrow[r]{}[,label=above:\scriptsize $f$]{}
    & F
        \arrow[r]{}[,label=above:\scriptsize $g$]{}
    & G
\end{tikzcd}
}
bar

\end{document}
```

while the commutative diagramm is compiling correctly when it's not in the margin.

Error is :

> ! Undefined control sequence. 
>   \pgf@matrix@last@nextcell@options ! Package pgf Error: Single
>   ampersand used with wrong catcode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a wellknown issue, when it is dealing with `&` used inside an argument, things go wrong (presumably catcodes). Solution use this:

```
\marginpar{
\begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&]
    E 
        \arrow[bend right=50]{rr}[,label=below:\scriptsize $g\circ f$]{}
        \arrow[r]{}[,label=above:\scriptsize $f$]{}
    \& F
        \arrow[r]{}[,label=above:\scriptsize $g$]{}
    \& G
\end{tikzcd}
}
```